# VBA Boolean UDF function returns #VALUE error

Tags: excel, vba, function, error-handling

I wrote a function that looks for a specific txt (`training_id_cell.Text`) inside a range (`prerequisites`) and checks if a cell with the text is red.
This is why I wrote this function

```vb
Public Function ISIDRED(training_id_cell As Range) As Boolean
    Dim cw As Worksheet
    Dim prerequisites As Range
    Dim prerequisite_cell As Range
    Dim prerequisite_cell_txt As String

    Set cw = Sheets("NAME")
    'Application.Volatile
    ISIDRED = False
    
    Set prerequisites = Range("$D$11:$H$34")

    For Each prerequisite_cell In prerequisites.Cells
        prerequisite_cell_txt = prerequisite_cell.Text
        If prerequisite_cell_txt = training_id_cell.Text And prerequisite_cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
            ISIDRED = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next prerequisite_cell
End Function
```

The procedure in VBA is below:

```vb
Sub IsIDRedTest()
    Application.Volatile
    Dim training_id_cell As Range
    Dim prerequisites As Range
    Dim cw As Worksheet
    Dim prerequisite_cell As Range
    Dim prerequisite_cell_txt As String
    Dim training_id_cell_txt As String

    Set cw = Sheets("NAME")

    Set training_id_cell = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Give Range of a training ID cell", Type:=8)
    Debug.Print training_id_cell_txt
    Set prerequisites = Range("$D$11:$H$34")

    For Each prerequisite_cell In prerequisites.Cells
        prerequisite_cell_txt = prerequisite_cell.Text
        Debug.Print "FOR: prerequisite_cell_address: "; prerequisite_cell.Address
        Debug.Print "FOR: prerequisite_cell_txt: "; prerequisite_cell_txt
        Debug.Print "FOR: if: "; prerequisite_cell_txt = training_id_cell.Text
        Debug.Print "FOR: prerequisite_cell_normal_color: ", prerequisite_cell.Interior.Color
        Debug.Print "FOR: prerequisite_cell_display_color ", prerequisite_cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
        If prerequisite_cell_txt = training_id_cell.Text And prerequisite_cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
            Debug.Print "TRUE"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next prerequisite_cell
End Sub
```

The function is giving `#VALUE!` error. Can you give me a hint why?

Comment: you cannot use `DisplayFormat` in a UDF called from the sheet.  See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.displayformat

Comment: @ScottCraner
I did it and it gives no error at all. I will edit the post and add a procedure code.

Comment: You will need to test the same thing that the conditional format is testing instead of testing the color.

Comment: one other comment:  You set a worksheet variable then never use it.  and as such the parent of `Range("$D$11:$H$34")` is assumed to be on the sheet in which the formula is placed.

Comment: Also I'd use `.Value` instead of `.Text`.